# Set Content-Type and Content-Encoding header of s3 object using ansibles s3_sync or related module

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

Using ansible's `s3_sync` module (task below) doesn't specify a Content-Type header and then it's not decipherable by the browser. I'm wondering how to set the Content-Type header either with the `mime_type` option or another ansible module.

```
  - name: S3 | sync gzip assets in build directory
    s3_sync:
      aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
      bucket: "{{ s3_bucket }}"
      file_root: "{{ s3_sync_dir }}"
      mime_map:
        .gz: application/gzip
        .json: application/text
        .png: image/png
        .ico: image/vnd.microsoft.icon
        .svg: image/svg+xml
      file_change_strategy: force
      permission: public-read
      cache_control: "public, max-age=31536000"
      include: "*"
      region: us-east-1
```

[image]

I would like to do something like:

```
  mime_map:
    .js.gz: 
        headers: "Content-Encoding=application/gzip, Content-Type=application/js"
    .css.gz: 
        headers: "Content-Encoding=application/gzip, Content-Type=text/css"
    .json: application/text
    .png: image/png
    .ico: image/vnd.microsoft.icon
    .svg: image/svg+xml
```

**Please note:** the files are hashed to bust browser cache, so any solution will need pattern matching like: `files: **/*.js.gz, headers: "Content-Type=application/javascript"`

Comment: Sorry, no, [only `ContentType` is sent](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.9/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/s3_sync.py#L453-L455); you will have to copy that file to the `library` of your playbook and modify it if you wish, or [open an issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/issues) for them to consider fixing it

Comment: Bummer. Thanks @mdaniel for the guidance.